# Reliable UDP algorithm implements

Tags: java

This is the first time I ask something on this site. If there is any mistake, please gentle to me.

I'm trying to write a 'reliable' file transfer using UDP.
The idea is the server split the file to many parts. Each parts contains many packets.
The server try to send all packets in one part and wait the client response.
The client receive packets and check if there is any lost packet. If yes, send response to the server and let it know which packet is lost.
The server receive the response from client and resend those lost packets.
If there is no packet lost, the server switch to next part and continue until the end.

That is the idea and this is the actual code

```
public void Send() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(4567);
    File file = new File("D:\\DOWNLOAD\\HC.flac");
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte[] b = new byte[10000];
    //calculate file length
    int remainLength = (int) file.length();

    //calculate total packet will be sent
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    int totalPacket = remainLength / 10000 + 1;
    bbuf.putInt(totalPacket);
    byte[] result = bbuf.array();
    //send total packet to client
    DatagramPacket total_Packet = new DatagramPacket(result,result.length,InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5"), 4567);
    ds.send(total_Packet);

    //position of packet is being sent (in total packets)
    int packetNumber = 0;

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
    try {

        while (remainLength != 0) {
            //create an array of packet, the client has a same array
            //this array is in order to make all receive packet (on client) is in order and check if there is any lost packet
            PacketSend[] windowBuffer = new PacketSend[1000];
            //position of packet is being sent (in windowBuffer) 
            int windowIndex = 0;

            //this while loop assign packet into windowBuffer
            while (remainLength >= 10000) {
                //read file
                b = new byte[10000];
                f.read(b, 0, 10000);
                //create packet with its position
                PacketSend fs = new PacketSend(packetNumber,windowIndex, b);
                //assign packet into window
                windowBuffer[windowIndex] = fs;

                //subtract the remaining length of file by 10000 (1 packet hold 10000 byte data of the file)
                remainLength = remainLength - 10000;

                packetNumber++;
                //if windowIndex = 999, that means the windowBuffer hold full of packet, ready to send to client
                if (windowIndex == 999)
                    break;
                windowIndex++;

            }
            //if this is the last packet
            if (remainLength > 0 && remainLength < 10000) {
                //only read the remaining
                b = new byte[remainLength];
                int read = f.read(b, 0, remainLength);
                PacketSend fs = new PacketSend(packetNumber,windowIndex, b);
                windowBuffer[windowIndex] = fs;

                remainLength = 0;
            }

            //this for loop send all the packet in windowBuffer to client
            for (int j = 0; j <= windowIndex; j++) {
                //serialize packet before send
                ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                        10076);
                ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                oos.writeObject(windowBuffer[j]);
                oos.close();
                byte[] serialize = new byte[10076];
                serialize = bStream.toByteArray();

                //send packet to client
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(serialize,
                        serialize.length,
                        InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5"), 4567);
                System.out.println("Sending " + serialize.length
                        + " bytes to client, port 4567, packet: "
                        + windowBuffer[j].packetNumber);

                ds.send(dp);

                //remove this line make the program always fail (because to many packets lost and it is easier for you to know what problem I am asking)
                //if this line exist, the program sometimes fail, sometimes work and I dont know why
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            }

            //ds.setSoTimeout(2500);
            //when all packets in windowBuffer are sent to client
            //this while loop handle the lost packets
            while(true){

            byte[] requestedPacket = new byte[10000];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(requestedPacket,
                    requestedPacket.length);
            try{
                //the server stop and wait for response from client
                //sometimes it just stop at there
                //I know UDP is unreliable, so the response from client may get lost, but I made the client resend its response to make sure server received
                //but it sometimes just stuck forever
                //Here is the problem I am asking
            ds.receive(dp);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException ste){
                ds.close();
                break;
            }
            //deserialize the response from client
            ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(requestedPacket));
            ArrayList<Integer> missingPacket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            //The response from client is an array of lost packets position (in windowBuffer)
            missingPacket = (ArrayList<Integer>) iStream.readObject();

            //if there is no lost packet, break this while loop
            //it mean move the windowBuffer to the next part of the file
            //the client move its windowBuffer too
            if (missingPacket.size() == 0){
                break;
            }


            System.out.printf("Resending %d missing packet.\n",missingPacket.size());
            //resend those lost packets
            //all the packets is still hold in windowBuffer, if you know which packet is missing, just resend them.
            for (int i = 0; i < missingPacket.size(); i++){
                //serialize
                ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                        10076);
                ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                oos.writeObject(windowBuffer[missingPacket.get(i)]);
                oos.close();
                byte[] serialize = new byte[10076];
                serialize = bStream.toByteArray();

                //and send
                DatagramPacket dtp = new DatagramPacket(serialize,
                        serialize.length,
                        InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.5"), 4567);
                System.out.println("Sending " + serialize.length
                        + " bytes to client, port 4567, packet: "
                        + windowBuffer[missingPacket.get(i)].packetNumber);
                ds.send(dtp);
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            }

            }

            //--------------------------------------------
            //ket thuc xu ly mat goi tin
        }
        System.out.println("File Transfer completed !!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found :P");
    }

    finally {
        f.close();

    }
}
```

Receiver end:

```
    public void Receive() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(4567);
    try {

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[10103];
        byte[] receiveNumPacket = new byte[4];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\TESTED\\Desktop\\abc\\test.mp3" + ""));
        {
            ds.setSoTimeout(10000);
            //receive total packets number from server
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(receiveNumPacket, receiveNumPacket.length);
            ds.receive(p);

        }
        //calculate number of total packet from byte array
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(receiveNumPacket);
        int totalPacket = bb.getInt();

        int windowSize = 1000;

        //set the timeout
        //if the timeout passed, it mean the server sent all its packet in windowBuffer and waiting for response
        ds.setSoTimeout(500);

        Outer: while (totalPacket > 0) {

            PacketSend[] windowBuffer = new PacketSend[1000];

            Inner: while (true) {
                try {

                    receiveData = new byte[10103];
                    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    //receive data from server
                    //if this packet lost, the program should fail. This is not the problem I'm asking
                    ds.receive(dp);
                    byte[] b1 = new byte[dp.getLength()];

                    //deserialize
                    ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(receiveData));
                    PacketSend fr = new PacketSend();

                    //assign the receive packet to windowBuffer
                    fr = (PacketSend) iStream.readObject();
                    windowBuffer[fr.bufferIndex] = fr;
                    iStream.close();

                    System.out.printf("Receive packet number: %d \n", fr.packetNumber);

                    //timeout passed, it mean the server sent all its packet in windowBuffer and waiting for response
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {

                    while (true) {
                        //check if this is the last part of the file
                        if (totalPacket < 1000)
                            windowSize = totalPacket;

                        //check if there is any packet lost
                        //those lost packets position will be hold in missingPacket array
                        ArrayList<Integer> missingPacket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
                            if (windowBuffer[i] == null) {
                                missingPacket.add(i);
                            }

                        }
                        //if there is any lost packet
                        if (missingPacket.size() != 0) {

                            //serialize missingPacket array
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10000);
                            ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                            oos.writeObject(missingPacket);
                            oos.close();
                            byte[] serialize = new byte[10000];
                            serialize = bStream.toByteArray();

                            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(serialize, serialize.length,
                                    InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"), 4567);
                            System.out.println("Request missing packet " + serialize.length
                                    + " bytes to server, port 4567, number of lost packets: "
                                    + missingPacket.size());

                            //send response to server, let it know which packet is lost
                            ds.send(dp);
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
                            //continue inner loop
                            //it mean try to receive packet from server and do the check
                            continue Inner;

                        }
                        //if all packet in windowBuffer received

                        ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10000);
                        ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                        oos.writeObject(missingPacket);
                        oos.close();
                        byte[] serialize = new byte[10000];
                        serialize = bStream.toByteArray();

                        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(serialize, serialize.length,
                                InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"), 4567);
                        System.out.println("Notice server all packet received");
                        //send response to server
                        //but this time, the missingPacket array have no member
                        //this also the sign for the server know it's time for move its windowBuffer to new position
                        ds.send(dp);
                        totalPacket -= 1000;


                        //write file to disk
                        for (int i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
                            fos.write(windowBuffer[i].data, 0, windowBuffer[i].data.length);
                        }
                        //continue the outer loops
                        //it mean move windowBuffer to new position
                        continue Outer;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        fos.close();
        System.out.println("File Transfer completed !!");
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        System.out.println("UDP Port is occupied.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

---

public class PacketSend implements Serializable{

```
public int packetNumber;
public int bufferIndex;
public byte[] data = new byte[1024];

public PacketSend(int _packetNumber,int _indexInBuffer,byte[] _data)
{
    packetNumber = _packetNumber;
    bufferIndex = _indexInBuffer;
    data = _data;
}
public PacketSend(){}
public PacketSend(PacketSend fs)
{
    packetNumber = fs.packetNumber;
    bufferIndex = fs.bufferIndex;
    data = fs.data;
}
```

But sometimes the program work and sometimes it fail. It fail at the line where the server stop and wait for response from client. The client try to resend the response to server but it seems the server not receive any of them.

When I try to use those code to make a multi threaded GUI program, the problem go worse. It stuck at that line every time.

I run the server in real machine and the client in vmware, both connect to real LAN router.

If anyone know what cause the problem please let me know. Explain as simple as you can because I'm not an English speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you want to use UDP? Why not TCP? TCP provide reliable delivery with inbuild acks.

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to do this, rather than just use TCP. You likely have an XY Problem here . Please elaborate.

Comment: I know TCP is better but using UDP is a requirement.

Comment: This is just a general comment not related to the question, try to remove the Labels, they are Java Equivalent to GOTO that are just a bad idea,

Comment: For anyone wonder why I don't use TCP. Because it's a homework for deep understanding how TCP work. Actually, I try to simulate Selective Repeat sliding window protocol with 'easier' approach (in my opinion).
I try to make sliding window only move at fixed position instead of move like Selective Repeat sliding window protocol do.

Comment: Can you please add the exact error messages when it fails? Also, have you created scenarios where it consistently fails or passes? Can you describe such scenarios (where it fails and where is passes)?